# how can i check url "\\abc\wof\TY044-12" exist

Tags: asp.net

i 've tried using

> ```
> string path= "\\abc\wof\TY044-12";
> bool exist=System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
> ```

but 'bool'  return true on localhost but return false on server side.
Also, i've searched some answers, but it is difficult reconfigure permission of IIS.

can i use FileWebrequest/httpWebRequest command? not understand about this

> ```
>         FileWebRequest request = (FileWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("\\abc\wof\TY044-12");
>         FileWebResponse response = (FileWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
> ```

Ihope someone can help me. THANKS!!!

Comment: What error are you getting? Perhaps you need to set permissions?

Comment: directory exist but 'bool exist= 'false'" so i cannot open directory through \\abc\wof\TY044-12

Comment: That looks more like a UNC.

To me it seems the appool account on iis which is hosting your application doesn't have permissions to access that UNC folder. Please refer following link to set it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: thanks,i will look for it ,but another question is can i know it is a valid path by using FileWebrequest/httpWebRequest command

Answer (score 1):

That looks more like a UNC.

To me it seems the appool account on iis which is hosting your application doesn't have permissions to access that UNC folder. Please refer link below to set it:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

The link below says you can access files over the network using pre-registered reserved types like http, https, file, etc.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

...And if you pass unc paths to the Uri class during construction, you can get the required uri scheme:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"\\abc\folder\file.jpg");
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString()); //outputs - file://abc/folder/file.jpg
```

However the recommended approach is using classes in the System.IO namespace like you originally started out with.

Comment: i get a message about"Access to the path '\\abc\wof' is denied." what is the problem, should i reconfigure the permssion of IIS